# Cross compile tensorflow-addons for aarch64 with Bazel

Tags: python, tensorflow, build, bazel, arm64

Is is possible to cross compile tensorflow-addons (tfa) (https://www.tensorflow.org/addons) for aarch64 with bazel? And if yes, how can I do it or are there maybe some prebuild binaries laying around somewhere?

I guess it is somehow possible because you can build tensorflow for aarch64 as well but I'am not in compiling that well and I don't know how to accomplish this task.

Here is the normal way to build tfa (https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/master/docs/overview.md#installing-from-source)

## Installing from Source

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/addons.git
cd addons

[...]

# This script links project with TensorFlow dependency
python3 ./configure.py

bazel build build_pip_pkg
bazel-bin/build_pip_pkg artifacts

pip install artifacts/tensorflow_addons-*.whl
```

#### Thanks in advance!